# Loading geometry point tables in SQL Server Spatial

Tags: sql-server-spatial

I need to load point data in SQL Server Spatial.

Similar to this post but I really don't know how to get XY data to be accessible by SQL

I want to do what was done in the initial part of this post (Identify points that plot inside the polygon):

[How do I find points that are NOT within a list of polygons using MS SQL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166399/how-do-i-find-points-that-are-not-within-a-list-of-polygons-using-ms-sql)

```
SELECT points.name, polygons.name
    FROM points CROSS JOIN
    polygons
    WHERE  (polygons.shape.STContains(points.shape) = 1)
```

How do you get the points loaded into your table and SQL to recognize the points with out having to define them like the below?

```
insert into @points values 
(geometry::Point(1,1,0)), 
(geometry::Point(2,3,0)), 
(geometry::Point(5,4,0)), 
(geometry::Point(4,2,0))
```

I am having a hard time defining points without doing it manually like above.

Ideally I could build a table like this by selecting the xy data I have in a table already.

Comment: It's important to understand that "SQL" and "Microsoft SQL Server" are different things, and referring to them both by just "SQL" can be confusing.

Comment: Understood, I am working in a SQL only environment, running SQL scripts that I execute in the query window of SQL Management studio. Does this help clarify? I am sort of over my head here at the moment. The post I referenced seemed to be about using SQL only but I really am not sure.

Comment: What is your source data? (csv, shapefile etc.?)

Comment: I am loading it from a csv into SQL Management. Studio. I am having a hard time applying the spatial functions to anything more than a singularly declared point. How can I load these functions with specific results, like from a query?

Comment: Are you trying to understand how you load lat long data in a csv file into a sql server table?

Comment: jport, No, I can get data into tables fine. It is applying the spatial functionality of MSSQL that I am struggling with. I am unsure if I am attempting something that doesn't work the way that I envision it does or if I am just going about it incorrectly.